# Problema en una entrada en C

Tags: c

Alguien me podria explicar o decir, ¿Por qué no entra el código? Si sale `0`, solo se termina.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dibujos.h"
#include <time.h>  
int main(){
    char pal_1 [12] = "hogar";          
    char let;                                  
    int vidas = 0;                             
    srand(time(NULL));

    system("cls");
    TituloJuego();
    SinAhorcado();
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    int pal = rand() % 10;                    
    printf("%d" , pal);
    if(pal = 0){
        while (vidas !=0){
        system("cls");
        TituloJuego();
        SinAhorcado();
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Palabra secreta:_ _ _ _ _ \n");
        printf("Ingrese una letra: ");
        scanf("%c", &let);
        if( let = "b" || "B" || "c" || "C" || "d" || "D" || "e" || "E" ||
            "f" || "F" || "i" || "I" || "j" || "J" || "k" || "K" || "l" ||
            "L" || "m" || "M" || "n" || "N" || "p" || "P" || "q" || "Q" ||
            "s" || "S" || "t" || "T" || "u" || "U" || "v" || "V" || "w" || 
            "W" || "x" || "X" || "y" || "Y" || "z" || "Z"
        ){
            system("cls");
            TituloJuego();
            Cabeza();
            printf("\n\n");
            system("pause");
            printf("hola");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: El main debe devolver un cero para indicar que se ejecutó correctamente, `return 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

Empecemos por lo más básico:

Las comparaciones en C se efectúan de la siguiente manera:

```
if (izq <operador> der) { /* ... */ }
O:
if (true||false) { /* ... */ }
```

Donde:

1. `izq`: Es el operando en la mano izquierda, una variable o un valor a comparar.
2. `<operador>`: Puede ser cualquiera de los operadores de comparación:

   - `<=` : Menor o igual qué
   - `<`  : Menor qué
   - `==` : Igual qué
   - `!=` : Diferente de
   - `>`  : Mayor qué
   - `>=` : Mayor o igual qué
3. `der`: Valor o variable que esperamos que tenga *(o no)* el lado izquierdo.

Lo que comparas actualmente:

```
if (let = "string" || "otro string")
Y:
if (pal = 0)
```

<s>Debería causar un error en tiempo de compilación, dado que `let` es de tipo `char` y no `char*`, aunque no soy muy bueno con C, por lo que no puedo opinar al respecto, los chars se encasillan dentro de comillas simples (`'`), y no dobles (`"`)</s>, actualmente, si compila, pero resulta que evalúa cualquier cadena de caracteres, por lo que será siempre verdadera.

Sobre el asunto de la asignación en una comparación, está mal planteado, al hacer:

```
if (pal = 0)
```

Estas asignando cero a `pal`, lo que al final se traduce a la siguiente comparación:

```
if (0)
```

Y en C, `0` significa falso.

Otra cosa, `scanf("%c", /* ... */);` está esperando un tipo `char`, por lo que no puedes comparar `let` con un char array, en su lugar, *puedes* comparar de la siguiente manera:

```
if ((let >= 'b' && let <= 'z') || (let >= 'B' && let <= 'Z')) {
    /* ... */ 
}
```

¡Ah! Las `vidas`, creo... que siempre serán cero, por lo que nunca entrará en el ciclo `while`, y si es diferente de cero, no hay ningún método o acción que permita el cambio de valor de esa variable.

Entonces, dejando todo el código:

```
int main(){
    char pal_1 [12] = "hogar";          
    char let;                                  
    int vidas = 5;                             
    srand(time(NULL));

    system("clear");

    int pal = rand() % 10;                    
    printf("%d\n" , pal);
    if(pal == 0) {
        while (vidas != 0) {
            system("clear");
            printf("Palabra secreta:_ _ _ _ _ \n");
            printf("Ingrese una letra: ");
            scanf("%c", &let);

            if((let >= 'b' && let <= 'z') || (let >= 'B' && let <= 'Z')) {
                printf("hola");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

He quitado todas las funciones de impresión (Y las demás que has puesto porque no iba a compilar si las dejaba).

Espero te haya ayudado :D

Comment: Un pequeño inciso: `if` evalua si el resultado de la comparación es verdadero o falso... será falso cuando el resultado sea 0 y verdadero en caso contrario. Es por esto que `if( a = "algo")` siempre es verdadero (La posición de memoria de "algo" es distinta de 0, mientras que `if( a = 0 )`  siempre será falso.

Comment: @eferion Me di cuenta de eso cuando probaba el código :P por eso he subrayado esa parte