# Estructura repetitiva Do-while en Lenguaje C

Tags: c

Estoy teniendo problemas con esta estructura de repetición Do While.
Necesito pedir al usuario un número entero y realizar la tabla de multiplicar de ese número del 1 al 10, luego preguntar si desea consultar otra tabla.
Si presiona la tecla s, lo hace nuevamente, si presiona n finaliza y da un mensaje de agradecimiento.
Quisiera que me ayuden a encontrar el error, creo que es de sintaxis. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Éste es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    int i, num, producto;
    char seguir;
    do {
        printf("\nIntroduzca un número entero: ");
        scanf("%i", &num);
        printf("\nLa tabla de multiplicar del %i es:\n\n", num);
        for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
            {
            producto=num*i;
            printf("%i * %i = %i\n", i, num, producto);
            }
        printf("\n¿Desea ver otra tabla (s/n)?: ");
        scanf("%c", &seguir);
    } while (seguir='s');
    printf("\nHa finalizado el programa.\n");
    printf("¡Gracias por utilizarlo!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25129/4499

Comment: Si, me faltó agregar el == pero lo compilo y ejecuto y ni siquiera me permite ingresar la entrada de teclado para preguntar si deseo continuar o no el programa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Si, me faltó agregar el == pero lo compilo y ejecuto y ni siquiera me permite ingresar la entrada de teclado para preguntar si deseo continuar o no el programa

El problema es que, para leer un caracter, `scanf` no elimina el salto de línea previo... prueba con esto:

```
scanf(" %c", &seguir);
//     ^ un espacio
```

Comment: Posible [duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92331/problema-al-leer-caracteres-con-scanf-en-c) entonces?

Comment: @NaCl más bien si... bien visto

Comment: ¡Tenías razón! ¡Funcionó! ¡Gracias!
Un poco antes encontré otra solución agregando la instrucción fflush(stdin); antes de realizar scanf (pero no conozco esta instrucción)

Comment: @NéstorJ **no uses** fflush... no se garantiza su uso con flujos de entrada

Comment: No lo haré, solo lo probé y funcionó antes que me des tu respuesta, que es mucho más simple. Recién estoy comenzando a programar en C y estoy aprendiendo los "trucos" para resolver errores